# amCharts - How can I use non-English calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar, amcharts

Is there any way to use the **Persian or Arabic calendar** in **Amcharts trendline**?
Months names are not useful, because they conflict with other calendars.

[AmCharts Live Editor](http://live.amcharts.com/)

Comment: Have you solved this ?

Comment: @jones no , i can't solve that

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to make JavaScript file named fa.js with code below in Lang folder which is available in amChart directory.

```
AmCharts.translations.fa = {
"monthNames": ["دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذز"],
"shortMonthNames":  ["دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذز"],
"dayNames": ["یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه"],
"shortDayNames": ["یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه"],
"zoomOutText": "نمایش همه"}
```

Now you have to do couple things more:

Import fa.js to your project

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/amcharts/lang/fa.js"></script>
```

Then define it in amchart object

```
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "dark",
    "marginRight": 40,
    "marginLeft": 40,
    "language":"fa"
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: this is ok , but date shown as gregorian calendar not persian calendar

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have to regenerate the whole (Persian Sunny) Calendar with the amCharts methods to format or parse dates

You can find the information related to formatting dates on

[amCharts Acknowledge Base - Date Formatting](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/)

if you could do it please feel free to share it with us

Answer (score 0):

you can use dates objects to place your trendlines, unfortunately the live editor accepts only valid JSON so you might need to use date strings "2013-12-03" instead.

```
"trendLines": [{
  "finalDate": new Date(2014,11,3),
  "finalValue": 5,
  "initialDate": new Date(2014,11,1),
  "initialValue": 5,
}],
```